# How do you make an LED fan sign?

Tags: led

I was wondering how to make an LED fan sign that consists of 256 white LEDs. Forward voltage is: 3.0-3.2 and maximum current is 20mA. Not sure what voltage to use so I'm open to any suggestions on which approach is best. Also, how many resistors will be needed and what value? I'm new to this so I appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: You are asking for an entire project design. That's not what this site is here for. Look for similar projects online and follow a few tutorials. But don't expect anyone here to simply tell you how to make one of these. That's way outside the scope of EESE.

Comment: Use a higher voltage than the LED needs, and calculate the resistor to drop the extra voltage at 20mA. You can connect several LEDs and one resistor in a series string, given enough voltage - for example 3 LEDs leaves 3V across the resistor from 12V.

Comment: @DerStrom8 As I've clearly stated I said I appreciate ANY help. I'm new to this so I want to get advice from people who know more about the subject. I've done a lot of research but nothing helps. As a beginner, I think it's best to be safe and ask for some help instead of just going for it and hope that I'm doing it right.

Comment: Kudos for researching voltage & current requirements. Your 256 LED array suggests a matrix of 8x8. But consider, if all 256 were lit, your array driver would draw over 5 amps - that's some serious electronics!

Comment: @glen_geek Now that I think about it I think I am going to change my sign in order to use less LEDs. This may be more advanced than I thought.

Comment: If you have done some research, please describe and/or link to it in your question, to help potential answerers and future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many handy online calculators that will help you determine the optimal configuration of your LEDs. How many to put in series.  What resistors to use. What supply voltage will be optimal, etc.   Examples:

- http://ledcalc.com/
- http://led.linear1.org/led.wiz
- http://www.hebeiltd.com.cn/?p=zz.led.resistor.calculator

Note that higher supply (battery) voltage will likely be more efficient.  I would consider putting a string (8-10-12, etc.) of C-cells (or D-cells) in series. You might even be able to find a plastic tube that you could put the batteries into that would also serve to hold up the sign.